# How to call group_ungroup operations when using blender is a python module

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I want to ungroup a node group when writing a script launched from a python command line, and I try to use `group_ungroup` as follows:

```py
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
                ctx = bpy.context.copy()
                ctx['area'] = area
                bpy.ops.node.group_ungroup(override_context=ctx)
                break
```

This throws a RuntimeError for running under the wrong context. If there anyway I can make it work? I am running under bpy=3.6.0 for python.

Comment: The issue is to make https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/b61496c5089260a5a35ed4863685ef072e7c5e79/source/blender/editors/space_node/node_group.cc#L88 to be true